# Trying to right justify "Like Us On Facebook Code" in Header

Tags: facebook, header, facebook-like

So I am trying to add the following "Like Us On Facebook" code in the header of my website and have it be right justified, while the Title & Description remain left justified. Here is the FB code:

```
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/HowToForiPad" data-width="292" data-show-faces="false" data-stream="false" data-header="false"></div>
```

I'm not the most knowledgeable about this type of thing so I'd prefer not to mess with the CSS and have been just trying to drop the code above into the appropriate place in my header.php file.  The tricky part (for me) is making the Facebook Like right aligned while the site title and description remain left aligned.

Here is an example of what I want it to look like (ignore the underscores...had to do it to make it look right)

WELCOME TO WHATEVER SITE
The site does blah blah_***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**_Like us on facebook

Here is the relevant code from the header.php:

```
        <!-- HEADER -->
        <div id="header">
            <div class="website-name"><a href="<?php echo home_url(); ?>/"><?php bloginfo('name'); ?></a></div>
            <div class="slogan"><?php bloginfo('description'); ?></div>
        </div>
        <!-- /HEADER -->
```

So basically I'd like the Facebook code to be in line with the site description but right justified (whereas the site description is left justified).

Greatly appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

Using CSS is pretty much your only option.

You can change the slogan div to a span (or set a width on the div), add the fb like box below this span and float it right.  That should do what you need.

If you REALLY don't want to touch your CSS file, you can add the styles inline, but I don't recommend this as it is not best practice.